# Using closures for specifying default parameter values in Groovy

Tags: grails, groovy, parameters, closures

Let's consider the next function:

```
def generateUniqueIdent(String text, uniqueSuffix = {uid -> String.valueOf(uid)}) {
   doSomething(text) + uniqueSuffix()
}
```

Now, when I try the next modification:

```
def generateUniqueIdent(String text, uniqueSuffix = { hash(text) }) {
   doSomething(text) + uniqueSuffix()
}
```

..I got the next error:

> | Error Fatal error during compilation
>   org.apache.tools.ant.BuildException: BUG! exception in phase 'class
>   generation' in source unit 'some path here' tried to get a variable
>   with the name **text** as stack variable, but a variable with this
>   name was not created (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)

At the same time, if I try to use the name `text` as a parameter of the closure:

```
def generateUniqueIdent(String text, uniqueSuffix = {text -> hash(text) }) {
   doSomething(text) + uniqueSuffix(text)
}
```

..then I got another error:

> The current scope already contains a variable of the name **text**

The question is: can I somehow get access to other parameters from a closure, which is assigned as a default value to one of function parameters?

If no, then, why can't I use the same name as one of function parameters has inside the described closure?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the default `it` parameter:

```
def generateUniqueIdent(String text, uniqueSuffix = { hash(it) }) {
   doSomething(text) + uniqueSuffix(text)
}
```

([working example](http://ideone.com/cuNTC))

Or use a different name for the closure parameter instead of `text`:

```
def generateUniqueIdent(String text, uniqueSuffix = { x -> hash(x) }) {
   doSomething(text) + uniqueSuffix(text)
}
```

([example](http://ideone.com/8SVxZ))

Unfortunately, accessing the previous parameter from the closure [is working](http://ideone.com/0fn17) for me in this case, so i don't know what the original problem is :S

Comment: Thanks for verifying, that it works. So, the problem either with my groovy/grails version, or with IDE plugin.

Comment: @Roman does the first or second solution work? If not, what's the error like?

Comment: @Roman I can get the `BUG!` exception if I set a default parameter for the `text` parameter.  I have posted a bug [here on the Groovy JIRA](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-5632)